# How can I print this table vertical?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

sign = "*"

x = int(input("Enter a number : "))
y = int(input("Enter a number : "))
z = int(input("Enter a number : "))

print(f'{"x":2}{"y":3}{"z":4}')
print(f'{x*sign}{y*sign}{z*sign}')
```

I want this to print like this but how can I take print it vertically?

```
x  y  z 
*  *  *
*  *
```

Comment: you have to use for-loop to print every row separatelly. And in every row you will have to put single `"*"` or `" "` (space) for every variable. OR first create 2D array (list of lines) with spaces and put `*` in correct places and finally print all lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` with a space as fillvalue, and a `for` loop:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

sign = "*"

x = int(input("Enter a number : "))
y = int(input("Enter a number : "))
z = int(input("Enter a number : "))

print(f'{"x":2}{"y":3}{"z":4}')
for a,b,c in zip_longest(x*sign, y*sign, z*sign, fillvalue=' '):
    print(f'{a:2}{b:3}{c:4}')
```

Example output:

```
x y  z   
* *  *   
* *  *   
*    *   
*    *   
*
```

##### alternative

If you don't have the specific formatting with different spaces you can even get rid of the (explicit) loop:

```
x,y,z = 5,2,4
print('x y z')
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip_longest(x*sign, y*sign, z*sign, fillvalue=' '))))
```

output:

```
x y z
* * *
* * *
*   *
*   *
*
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to print every rows separatelly and check `x`,`y`,`z` to print single `sign` or space `" "`

You can get max value form `x, y, z` and run `for`-loop with `range(max_val)`
and compare this value with `x, y, z` to check if it has to display `sign` or space.

```
sign = "*"

#x = int(input("Enter a number : "))
#y = int(input("Enter a number : "))
#z = int(input("Enter a number : "))
x = 5
y = 2
z = 4

print(f'{"x":2}{"y":3}{"z":4}')

maxval = max([x, y, z])

for n in range(maxval):
    sign_x = sign if n < x else " "
    sign_y = sign if n < y else " "
    sign_z = sign if n < z else " "
    print(f'{sign_x:2}{sign_y:3}{sign_z:4}')
```